# How to vectorize the forward method of this pytorch block?

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch

I am making a novel type of fully connected layer that operates with channels analogously to a 2D convolutional layer. Namely, each output channel is the sum of fully connected layers applied to the input channels. I have a fully working prototype below. But it is slow because of the for loops in the forward method. Theoretically all of these operations can happen in parallel. How can I achieve this? Thank you.

```
# assumes shape of input is (BATCH X channels X feature_dim)
class Channelwise_Linear(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self, in_channels, out_channels, in_feature_dim, out_feature_dim, drop_rate):
      super(Channelwise_Linear, self).__init__()
      self.in_channels = in_channels
      self.out_channels = out_channels
      self.in_feature_dim = in_feature_dim
      self.out_feature_dim = out_feature_dim

      self.linear_layers = []
      self.bn_layers = []
      self.activation_layers = []
      self.do_layers = []
      for out_channel in range(out_channels):
          temp_linear = nn.ModuleList()
          temp_bn = nn.ModuleList()
          temp_AL = nn.ModuleList()
          temp_do = nn.ModuleList()
          for in_channel in range(in_channels):
            temp_linear.append(nn.Linear(in_feature_dim, out_feature_dim))
            temp_bn.append(nn.BatchNorm1d(out_feature_dim))
            temp_AL.append(nn.LeakyReLU())
            temp_do.append(nn.Dropout1d(drop_rate))
          self.linear_layers.append(temp_linear)
          self.bn_layers.append(temp_bn)
          self.activation_layers.append(temp_AL)
          self.do_layers.append(temp_do)

  def forward(self, x):

      x = torch.transpose(x,0,1) # now channel is first

      output_list = []
      for out_channel in range(self.out_channels):
          temp = []
          for in_channel in range(self.in_channels):
            intermediate = self.linear_layers[out_channel][in_channel](x[in_channel])
            intermediate = self.bn_layers[out_channel][in_channel](intermediate)
            intermediate = self.activation_layers[out_channel][in_channel](intermediate)
            intermediate = self.do_layers[out_channel][in_channel](intermediate)
            temp.append(intermediate)
          temp = torch.sum(torch.stack(temp), axis=0) # each out_channel is the sum of the output of the nn.Linear(in_channels), like Conv2D

          output_list.append(temp)

      return torch.transpose(torch.stack(output_list), 0, 1) # switch the batch back to first dim
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're correct; the for loop can make your `forward` method quite slow. Here's a more efficient way of implementing your model with vectorized computation:

```py
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
import math

class Channelwise_Linear(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, in_channels, out_channels, in_feature_dim, out_feature_dim, drop_rate):
        super(Channelwise_Linear, self).__init__()

        self.in_channels = in_channels
        self.out_channels = out_channels

        # Weights and biases for linear layers for all in-channels and out-channels.
        self.weight = nn.Parameter(torch.Tensor(out_channels, in_channels, out_feature_dim, in_feature_dim))
        self.bias = nn.Parameter(torch.Tensor(out_channels, in_channels, out_feature_dim))

        self.batch_norm = nn.BatchNorm1d(out_channels)
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(drop_rate)
        self.reset_parameters()

    def reset_parameters(self):
        nn.init.kaiming_uniform_(self.weight, a=math.sqrt(5))
        fan_in, _ = nn.init._calculate_fan_in_and_fan_out(self.weight)
        bound = 1 / math.sqrt(fan_in)
        nn.init.uniform_(self.bias, -bound, bound)

    def forward(self, x):
        # Reshape x and weight to apply linear layer to each pair of out_channel and in_channel
        out = torch.matmul(self.weight, x.view(x.size(0), 1, self.in_channels, -1).unsqueeze(-1)).squeeze(-1) + self.bias

        # Flatten out for batch normalization and dropout
        out = out.view(x.size(0), self.out_channels, self.in_channels * out.size(-1))
        out = out.sum(2)
        
        out = self.batch_norm(out)
        out = F.leaky_relu(out)
        out = self.dropout(out)

        return out
```

I created the weight and bias for all pairs of output channels and input channels together, rather than creating them separately. I then reshape the input x and the weight such that the linear layer can be applied to each pair of output channel and input channel. The reshaped output can then be passed through batch normalization, activation, and dropout layers. I then reshape it back to its original shape and sum along the input channel dimension.

This implementation should be significantly faster than the original one with for loops. However, it uses a bit more memory to store intermediate computations, which might be a problem if your model is very large.

Note in the provided code, the `reset_parameters()` function initializes the weights using Kaiming Uniform initialization and the biases with a uniform distribution. This kind of initialization is commonly used, especially when ReLU (or its variants, like LeakyReLU used here) is the activation function, because it helps to keep the scale of the input variance constant across layers, reducing the risk of vanishing/exploding gradients.

It's good practice to define a separate method like reset_parameters() for this purpose, because it provides flexibility to change the initialization method later without modifying the constructor or forward methods. Also, if you want to reinitialize the model at some point (like if you want to restart training from scratch), you can easily do so by calling this method.

Comment: Why did you add the `reset_parameters()` to the code?  I'm curious because this isn't something the OP asked about, iiuc, and you don't mention it in your text.

Comment: Thank you NoName! I had to read this a few times to understand what was going on and this is indeed very clever. Unfortunately the F.linear function only accepts 2D inputs (or only uses the last dimension for larger inputs), so the current code gives the error:
"RuntimeError: t() expects a tensor with <= 2 dimensions, but self is 4D"
Should I replace this line with my own matrix multiplication of the weights and addition of the bias?

Comment: The reset_parameters() function is used to initialize the weights and biases of the model. While it's true that the OP didn't specifically ask about weight initialization, this is an important aspect of defining custom layers. PyTorch's built-in layers (like nn.Linear, nn.Conv2d, etc.) have their own default initialization methods. But when we create a custom layer with parameters (like in this case where we define the weight and bias manually), we need to handle the initialization ourselves while providing flexibility to change the initialization method later without modifying the constructor

Comment: Yes, you're right. My mistake, F.linear() expects 2D inputs. To handle this, we can perform the operations manually with torch.matmul(). See the corrected forward method above. I've replaced the F.linear() with torch.matmul() for the matrix multiplication and added the bias manually. Please note that unsqueeze(-1) is used to add an extra dimension to align the input for multiplication and squeeze(-1) is used to remove the extra dimension after the operation.

Comment: NoName, the correction is very close. I think the first dimension is the one that needs to be expanded, like this "out = torch.matmul(weight, x.view(x.size(0), 1, in_channels, -1).unsqueeze(-1)).squeeze(-1) + bias". If you make this correction I'll accept the answer. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Also batchnorm should be 1D

Comment: Yes, you're correct. My apologies for the oversight. The correct way to perform the multiplication would indeed be to expand the first dimension of x